# Trouble with query when my object has a property name starting with new (newStatus)

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have a property oldStatus and newStatus in my object and when I try to run a query on the object where newStart = approved. I am getting an error.

Seems like the newStatus is being treated as new Status() and getting an exception that object Status not found.

Anyone with similar issue? and possible solution.

```
Query query = pm.newQuery(Inquiry.class, " newStatus == 'CANCELED' ");
```

or

```
Query query = pm.newQuery(Inquiry.class); 
query.setFilter("newStatus == statusParam"); 
query.declareParameters("String statusParam");
List<Inquiry> pis = (List<Inquiry>)query.execute("CANCELLED");
```

CreatorExpression defined with class of Status yet this class is not found

Comment: Could you post some code (the query you're doing) and what error you're getting?

Comment: Added the sample code. Please check.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1344215/query-against-link-type-in-google-app-engine-datastore It's probably a bug if replacing the new make it work ..

Comment: yes, replacing the new works. I was wondering if there was a way to escape the keywords like %newStatus%  or so.

Answer (score 1):

stausParam != statusParam .. typo ?

Comment: sry that was a typo. The problem still exists.